# How I can directly load a decrypted file from CipherInputStream without storing it?

Tags: java, android

```
fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf_encrypt.enc");
fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.pdf");
CipherInputStream input = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
final byte[] decryptedData = new byte[4096];
int decryptedRead;
while ((decryptedRead = input.read(decryptedData)) >= 0) {
    fos.write(decryptedData, 0, decryptedRead);
}
```

Comment: where do you want to load it to?

Comment: i want to load it in pdf view

Comment: what exactly does your pdf view accept as input?

Comment: a .pdf file i.e (sample.pdf)

Comment: check what else. If the file is only option, then you have to save it first

Comment: i am using this barteksc:android-pdf-viewer library

Comment: I've fixed your formatting, but you should still [edit] your question and add more context. Please read [ask]. What exactly are you trying to do and why? What happens when you run the code you posted? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Also, always [edit] your question. Don't use comments to clarify: comments may or may not be shown initially, and in any order (usually by upvotes).

Comment: @Robert thank you for your suggestions and support. ;)

Comment: it has pdfView.fromBytes(byte[]) method. Just read that stream to byte array, and use this method